# Installing mysql noinstall zip archive

Tags: mysql, installation

I've been trying to use my mysql noinstall zip archive and the steps that I found in some of the websites are not descriptive. Can someone help?

Comment: unzip and mysqld --console didn't work? What have you tried instead?

Comment: I just ran the command and got the following 120822 16:47:59 [Note] 
120822 16:48:00 [Note] mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.65-community'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: now i got the server running. and have opened the mysql.exe which opens up the command line interface for mysql..it says i don't have privileges to create database :-(..What user does it take by default?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you follow the instruction [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-install-archive.html) you will be alright. From that page:

> Users who are installing from the noinstall package can use the instructions in this section to manually install MySQL. The process for installing MySQL from a Zip archive is as follows:
>
> - Extract the archive to the desired install directory
> - Create an option file
> - Choose a MySQL server type
> - Start the MySQL server
> - Secure the default user accounts

To start the sever run

```
mysqld --console
```

and after that run

```
mysql -u root
```

to start doing whatever you want.

Notice that MySql will function exactly the same as if you would have installed or configured it to run as a service. Your schema's are stored on disk. If you start it after you've stopped it your previous data will still be there. So it doesn't turn magically into an in-memory database.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to install the MySQL database as a service you can use the command below.

`mysqld.exe --install`

Comment: Thanks, and I need to create file `my.ini` in mysql dir, other the service can not start